# Installing Cinnamon DE on RHEL 7.5

Tags: linux, cinnamon, rhel-7

I have a ThinkPad T580 running RHEL 7.5. I have installed `epel` repo and am trying to install cinnamon DE.

I used the command `sudo yum groupinstall "Cinnamon Desktop" -y` to install the DE. The process fails with the following error message.

```
Error: Package: pix-1.6.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libexiv2.so.12()(64bit)
Error: Package: mint-y-theme-1.2.4-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: mint-y-icons
Error: Package: slick-greeter-1.1.4-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: mint-y-icons
Error: Package: lightdm-settings-1.1.4-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python-xapp
Error: Package: xviewer-plugins-1.2.0-5.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python34-xapps-overrides(x86-64)
Error: Package: xplayer-1.6.0-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python34-xapps-overrides(x86-64)
Error: Package: xplayer-1.6.0-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libxapp.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: cinnamon-applet-blueberry-1.1.20-6.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: cinnamon
Error: Package: xviewer-1.6.0-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: xapps(x86-64)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Googling around, I found the following discussions

1. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1578521
2. https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3539581s

suggesting that Cinnamon on RHEL 7.5 through the usual way is broken with no plans to fix in a timely manner. Any suggestions on work-arounds to get Cinnamon working on RHEL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess there's no easy way forward for now. I asked the same question on the RedHat subreddit and the new Cinnamon EPEL repo maintainer responded saying that it should be added to stable soon [Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/redhat/comments/aacser/installing_cinnamon_de_on_rhel_75/)